# c++ printing out incorrect binary after shifting << 32 times

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitset

The code below should be printing out 32 0s, then 011, then 0s till the 64 bit from right to left

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <stdint.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int a = 0b011;
  long long b = (a << 32);


  std::cout << bitset<64>(b).to_string();
}
```

but its giving this:

```
main.cpp:8:20: warning: shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
  long long b = (a << 32);
                   ^  ~~
1 warning generated.
```

And the incorrect input is this:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000101011110000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the shifting is done in 32-bit because both of `a` and `32` are 32-bit long.

Cast to `long long` before shifting to fix.

```
long long b = ((long long)a << 32);
```

Comment: Also consider `uint64_t` to make it clear what your "long long" thing actually is. Presumably unsigned is intended when using bit-shifting.